# Switching tabs from navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

[image: This is a picture of navigation drawer.]

[image: This is the picture of main activity]

I have a navigation drawer, and in main activity I have 3 tabs. I want to switch between tabs from navigation drawer click. 
Like I am now in Services tab. But when I have clicked Home in navigation drawer activity I want to see the Home tab.

Comment: Please provide some code and context

Comment: Why would you have tabs and a navigation drawer for the same elements? Just use one navigation mode

Comment: Client required so that I have to do that.

Comment: So, on selecting "Home" from nav-drawer, you want to show a viewpager, right? AND the tab you want to show after that click event is "Home" tab from viewpager, right? Use [setCurrentItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int)) appropriately

Answer (score 0):

correct code syntax is
`viewPager.setCurrentItem(0)` for Home tab. 
`viewPager.setCurrentItem(1)` for Services tab. 
`viewPager.setCurrentItem(2)` for About us tab

tab indexing starts from 0.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

       if (id == R.id.nav_home)
       {
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
       }
       else if (id == R.id.nav_aboutus)
       {
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        }
}
```